# Как настроить серверный рендеринг (SSR) используя ASP.NET Core 2.1 и Angular 6

Tags: c#, angular2, asp.net-core, angular-cli

Я нашел [документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio#server-side-rendering) для настройки SSR в ASP.NET Core 2.1 и Angular 5.2. Пошагово выполнив инструкцию я получил рабочий проект. Но я не смог найти подобной инструкции для работы с ASP.NET Core 2.1 и Angular 6. При обновлении  Angular 5.2 до Angular 6 проект перестает работать. Насколько я понимаю, новый Angular 6 изменил способ настройки приложения в файле angular.json и я не понимаю, как нужно изменить в нем настройки для того что бы проект снова заработал.

Хотелось бы попросить скинуть настройки angular.json либо ссылку на github с пустым настроенным проектом поддерживающим серверный рендеринг.

Comment: есть же документация https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-universal-rendering

Comment: @overthesanity Приблизительно, похожая документация есть на сайте angular.io, за исключением некоторых частей. Я работал по ней. Так ничего и не добившись. Может быть, потому, что там не указанны скрипты для файла packaj.json и по сравнению с вашим документацией отличаются данные которые необходимо указать в файле angular.json.

Comment: а какие скрипты нужны для файла `package.json` не пойму? и что значит по сравнению с МОЕЙ документацией - это оф. документация от команды `angular`, к тому же там все описано, что нужно указать в `angular.json` в разделе `Step 3: Create a new target in angular.json`

Comment: @overthesanity В теле моего вопроса ссылка на документация от Microsoft по работе с SSR в теле вашего комментария ссылка на документацию Angular. Предложенные ими реализации отличаются.

Comment: ваш вопрос `Хотелось бы попросить скинуть настройки angular.json` - я вам скинул ссылку, настройки нигде не будут отличаться, `angular.json` имеет везде одинаковую структуру

Comment: @overthesanity Не могу понять, зачем ставить дизлайк. Документация на которую я ссылаюсь в описании вопроса, содержит отличия от той что дали вы. На официальном сайте angular.io также есть отличия от той что дали вы. Наверное после мучений с документацией на сайте angular.io я мог откинуть информацию предоставленную по вашей ссылке, поскольку подумал, что они одинаковы. К тому же, я в своем вопросе сделал упор на то что меня интересует способ предоставленный Microsoft собственно я о ней и говорю в расшифровке вопроса.

Comment: @overthesanity судя по всему, вы плохо прочитали вопрос не заметив ссылку. ОТЛИЧИЯ В КОДЕ ДОКУМЕНТАЦИЙ ЕСТЬ. а в целом, если у вас так раздражает мой вопрос... то надо было на него не отвечать...

Comment: не будьте так самокритичны, ничего меня не раздражает :-) просто по опыту работы с юниверсалом я могу вам посоветовать отказаться от велосипеда с .net, потому что .net core внутри себя запускает ноду, то есть это эдакой сложный гибрид + вам будет очень тяжело дебажить все это

Comment: Спасибо за совет!) Я просто до конца не понимаю, чем в конечном итоге выльются отличия в доках от Microsoft и angular. Поэтому в итоге решил доверится Microsoft. В итоге, до сих пор ничего не получилось. В ссылке на указанную вами документацию есть некоторые упущенные строчки кода которых нет на сайте angular.io в разделе SSR. Я тогда попробую еще раз все сделать, только уже по вашей документации. Спасибо за ссылку.

Comment: доверяйте angular, а не майкрософт, не майкрософт же разрабатывает его :-) на проекте используйте просто ноду + любой фреймворк (express / koa), без оборачивания ноды дот нетом, вам это не выльется головной болью, к тому же представьте ситуацию, что процесс ноды упал по какой-то причине, такие пакеты как `pm2` разрулят такую ситуацию, а как быть с дот нетом? тут уж сами смотрите :-)